# Changing log levels per request in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

I have a Flask codebase with the standard library's logging module used throughout. I'd like to be able to increase and decrease the log level on a per-request basis. This way I could get trace or debug level information logged just on the specific requests I'm interested in debugging by setting a query string param or something similar to that.

I know that Flask has a before_request and after_request decorator that could be used to raise and lower the log level. However, it would be a bad deal if an unhandled exception is thrown and prevented the log level from being reset to its default level. Is there a reliable way to set and restore the log level per request?

I am also not very familiar with how the logging module interacts with threads and Flask. If a multi-threaded application server is running my Flask app is the logger shared across threads? I don't want to lower the log level in one request and have another, unrelated request execute with the first requests's logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Flask logger to create a child logger:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'trace' in request.args:
        trace_logger = app.logger.getChild('trace')
        trace_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        g._trace_logger = trace_logger
```

It will re-use the parent's configuration. Specifically, it'll use the handlers and formatters you've configured but not the parent's log level or filters.  The logger is also scoped to the request via the g object so it will not be available in other requests, making this design thread-safe.

Next, write a helper function:

```
def trace(*args, **kwargs):
    logger = getattr(g, '_trace_logger', None)
    if logger is not None:
        logger.debug(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use this function as if it were a logger call throughout your codebase. 
If you are not running in trace mode the function is a no-op.