# How do you change log level of specific routes in flask

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

This is my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

import logging

LOGLEVEL = os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO").upper()
logging.basicConfig(level=LOGLEVEL)
logger = logging.getLogger()

@app.route("/")
def splash():
    response = jsonify(success=True)
    return response

@app.route("/ready")
def ready():
    response = jsonify(success=True)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 80))
    host = "0.0.0.0"

    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

Currently when INFO log level is set calls to `/ready` are logged: `INFO:werkzeug:10.123.123.123 - - [18/Oct/2022 19:32:45] "GET /ready HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

How can I modify the log level of just the `/ready` path so responses are not logged in INFO level and are only logged in DEBUG level?

There is an existing SO post very similar to this one: [Changing log levels per request in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103458/changing-log-levels-per-request-in-flask)

Looking at that I tried doing this, but it does not change the loglevel:

```
@app.route("/ready")
def ready():
    route_logger = app.logger
    route_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    response = jsonify(success=True)
    return response
```

I also tried doing this but it did not do anything: `logging.getLogger("mymodule.ready").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`